# Change Typescript import directories during compilation for unit testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, es6-modules

Let's say I have a directory called `src` containing a file called `app.ts`

```
export default function app(){
    return "Hello World";
}
```

I have another directory called `test` containing a file called `some.test.ts`

```
import "mocha";
import { assert } from "chai";
import app from "../src/app"

describe("Some test", () => {
    it("says Hello World", function(){
        assert.equal(app(),"Hello World");
    });
})
```

And a `gulpfile.js` for building both the production and test code:

```
gulp.task("build", function () {
    var tsproject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
    var tsresult = gulp.src("./src/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(tsproject());

    tsresult.js
        .pipe(gulpBabel({ presets: ['es2015'] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"))

    tsresult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
});

gulp.task("build-test", ["build"], function () {
    var tsproject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
    var tsresult = gulp.src("./test/**/*.test.ts")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsproject());

    tsresult.js
        .pipe(gulpBabel({ presets: ['es2015'] }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/test"))

    tsresult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/test"));
});
```

My `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "es2015"
        "rootDir": "src"

    }
}
```

This will compile fine, but when I try to run the test, it won't work because it is looking for `../dist/src/app.js`.

I want to keep my source code in the `src` folder, but I want it to be compiled into the root of the `dist` folder. At the same time, I want to keep my imports so that my IDE can find them during development, while the compiled code can find them at runtime. I assume this would involve some sort of transformation of the import statements during compilation.

Is this at all possible using (preferably) Gulp?

Comment: Add your tsconfig.json. You probably just need to specify `--rootDir src`.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question with `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I've added `"rootDir": "src"` to it but it's still not working.

Comment: Any reason why you are not specifying `"outDir": "dist"` in `tsconfig`?

Comment: Because it's already specified in the `gulpfile.js` which I assume is enough? I did try setting `"outDir"` but VS Code won't find the imported modules and it won't compile.

Comment: `"outDir"` is preferable to specifying it via gulp. Anyway, what you almost certainly need is a `tsconfig.test.json` (or whatever you call it) that `"extends"` `tsconfig.json` but overrides the `"rootDir"` and `"outDir"`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look into that!